# why is fread() failing during file read?

Tags: c

Why I am getting :

> fread() failed

I am running this code in VS 2010

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 1
#define NUMELEM 5

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fd = NULL;
    char buff[100];
    memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));

    printf(" Starting to open");

    fd = fopen("test","r+");

    if(NULL == fd)
    {
        printf("\n fopen() Error!!!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n File opened successfully through fopen()\n");

    if(SIZE*NUMELEM != fread(buff,SIZE,NUMELEM,fd))
    {
        printf("\n fread() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

}

Comment: Does `test` have that many bytes in it?

Comment: What is the return value?  What are the contents of the file?  Have you debugged through fread to determine why it is failing?  (We ship the source code so that you can debug through it.)

Comment: possibly your `fread` is reaching upto end of file.

Comment: Read here: What [size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) **returns**?. You concept is not correct in two ways regarding return value. (1) `fread()` returns number of elements not total size. So in `if()` , `SIZE*NUMELEM` should be just `NUMELEM` (actually not even this read 2 point) (2) `fread()` can return *`The total number of elements successfully read is returned`* as in third argument you are trying to read mxm `NUMELEM` elements or less. So `if` should be `if(0 != (num= fread(buff,SIZE,NUMELEM,fd)))`

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't read the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fread.html) of `fread()`. It returns `NUMELEM`, and **not** `SIZE * NUMELEM`.

Comment: `SIZE` is defined to be `1` in the program in question, so `SIZE * NUMELEM == NUMELEM`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Theat's still wrong, however. But then, `fread()` is allowed to fail and return a smaller number. In this case, it fails. For some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare fread() return value with requested size. Some times requested size of data not available in the file.and don't compare with SIZE*NUMELEM,fread always returns number of items read successfully. For more information read manual page of fread()

Answer (score 1):

What if there are less number of characters stored in the file?
`fread()` ***returns the amount of characters*** that it has read from the file and in your code, the number of ***characters read != number of characters in the file***.